# Spring boot Oauth2 SSO with Zuul proxy and multiple clients (native, mobile, web)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, proxy, single-sign-on, netflix-zuul

I'm currently working on a project that uses Zuul to proxy requests to both API endpoints as well as client resources. There is an angular app that is being served from the same endpoint as the Zuul proxy as outlined in [this guide](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2). I have the need for additional clients, specifically a desktop application.

I'm not sure I understand how Zuul proxy handles requests and I think there are several paths to get to where I want to go, I'm just not sure what the correct one is.

Here is what I have surmised thus far:

Option 1: Extract the Zuul proxy and SSO capabilities to it's own server. Then create a new UI server which is behind the gateway server. Follow this up with creating a new client application server which handles the authentication of the desktop client.

Option 2: Extract the Zuul proxy and SSO capabilities to it's own server. Serve the current angular app from its own server NOT behind the proxy and change the authorization flow to something different (implicit). Alter Zuul proxy and SSO configuration to ignore requests that already have a bearer token in the header.

If I go with option 2 then I don't understand how to register with the Zuul gateway client that I already am providing the authorization header with my requests so all it should be doing then is proxying my requests to the correct microservices.

Final Questions:

- Which option is the most optimal one?
- If an access token is already acquired (directly from the auth server using implicit flow) then how does Zuul need to be configured to not try and acquire the access token using the jsessionid?